# Why don't my constraints and rig update when the target moves?

Tags: rigging, constraints

So I have this basic rig. I have an empty for each bone. Each bone has 'Damped track' to its empty. Each empty has 'limit distance'(from head). No problem with 'limit distance', 
but the 'Damped track' causes a few issues.
Grab the Empty and move, click <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of Mouse buttons. The Empty comes back to its original position, but the bone does not keep track.
 Press<kbd>G</kbd>(grab) and <kbd>Esc</kbd> again without moving the mouse. Then it tracks again.

This is making animation really difficult. I am having to render each frame manually because of this issue. Please help.
[image: constrain1]
[image]

Comment: What is the larger description of the animation? Many people would insert location keyframes for the empty rather than move it about manually. So the description of workflow seems unusual in a undesirable way. What positions will you locate the empty? The constraint looks like a Track to ... not a Damped track. If you are using keyframes please state so and your pictures should show keyframes in the timeline.

Comment: There's a circular reference, which the current dependency graph can't handle properly.

Answer (score 3):

**Use the arrow keys to go one frame forward and one frame backward.  This will cause a reposition and repaint.**

Currently that is the least burdening user action I have.

Also you have a Circular Reference.

[image]

**Check your [Console Window] to see a troubling circular reference. Remove the circular reference.**

[image]

This menu selection opens the console. Image above.

[image]

Often software needs to determine a work order by sorting dependencies of Constraints.  Precedence sorting.  Topological Sorting.  For explanation simplicity allow G->D to mean G depends on D. Clear chain of command is easier to understand.  Clear example A->B->C.  Unclear example A->B and B->A

Desired Situation

- Your empty constraint should refer to another bone prior to the current one, or the armature itself, or some other created object.

Current Situation Undesirable

- Your bone has a constraint that refers to the empty.  The empty has a constraint that refers to the bone.  A->B  and B->A.  Circular Reference.